Wallet (e.g solflare) might set prioritization fee, without asking me?
On devnet, usually my tx fee is 0.000005 Sol, for simple transfer of sol or token.
But, today I got several simple tx with fee higher than normal, with priority fee.
tx & fee list:

tx 1. fee = 0.0000149 https://solscan.io/tx/2a48rRuMFsD54uZ1X8Qan8yx7wuQmt4HqDWZfCqRa5cWh7D1wtccp2NtQ33pcxMb51Dg1ZCp6KS5352DgqzYkEo8?cluster=devnet
tx 2. fee = 0.00005109
https://solscan.io/tx/3U8HDGpYLqKPFsnSCVDBFSoKTPp7NfsiHga3dgJjhrZtU4evRcJjCF2AMfG7NuvUm2CGQnMEB8U2R4NNkUPvUHAq?cluster=devnet
tx 3. fee = 0.0001927
https://solscan.io/tx/44GsLhedCqFsjYXg1gk6vGfz2FSixuR31xfFmapFrFGQqEDGz4ecx9SZwvvYrjEaEcJpyvRn55vdRgcJoB8Lbsow?cluster=devnet

Questions:

1. Why these tx has fee higher than 0.000005, they are just simple tx, is it due to there are too much tx on devnet at the time when the tx is broadcast?
2. How can I limit the fee to 0.000005? Or, set another upper limit.
3. Who sets the priority fee in the above tx? I didn't specify such param I guess.


@Update
I see, there is SetComputeUnitLimit and SetComputeUnitPrice set, thus there is Priority Fee.
But I didn't set that, maybe the wallet (solflare) set that ? I'm not sure. The validator can't set that I think.
Questions:



Is the price default to 0?




Will wallet (e.g solflare) choose to set a price > 0, without asking me first?




The validators can't set the price, because private key is needed, right ?



